# Finding valuable conjectures from NP-Complete problems

Tags: np

Let's suppose we've got an NP-Complete problem, such as the subset sum problem. There are conjectures that, if proven true, would place the subset sum problem to the P-Complete problem realm?

If the answer is yes, then we could create an NP-Complete problem that relied on a known proof to become a P-Complete problem, thus proving that every NP-Complete problem can become a P-Complete problem if a proof of the right conjecture is found?

Comment: That does not make much sense to me: It is widely believed that P ≠ NP, and any 'conjecture' that would place an NP-complete problem into P would imply that P = NP. It seems that what you are asking is essentially equivalent to P = NP.

Comment: Most of us would be best advised to avoid working on any conjectures whose positive resolution would imply that P = NP.